# Coq: Language server crashes when trying to introduce an equality-hypothesis

Tags: coq

I'm working in Coq in VSCode (using VSCoq). Repeatedly the Coq language server crashes.

I try to prove the following:

```
Theorem plus_id_example : forall n m : nat, 
    n = m -> n + n = m + m.
Proof. 
  intros n m. (*works!*)
  intros H.   (*crash!*)
  rewrite -> H.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Up until the introduction of n and m everything works fine, as soon as I try to introduce H the language server immediately crashes. When the whole proof is written out as above and I restart VSCode the theorem and its proof are accepted! I can mostly move the cursor through the proof and the goal/proof state is displayed as expected. As soon as I put the cursor behind the "intros H." the server immediately crashes however. I have no clue how to proceed from here...

Comment: Which version of Coq/VSCoq are you using? Also, this kind of questions which requires interactive probing might be better suited for the [Coq Zulip](https://coq.zulipchat.com/), which has [a stream dedicated to VSCoq](https://coq.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/237662-VsCoq-devs-.26-users).

Comment: Thank you, I will try that!